# javascript to wait until DOM element is actually painted and done

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Is it possible to create a DOM element (say a DIV) and then wait until that element is actually in the browser before proceeding? Much like an ajax request has a "complete" event that you can use when chaining code, to guarantee that step one is finished before step2 begins.
Using jQuery by the way.

Comment: have you tried with any code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rely on [DOM mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events), specifically `DOMNodeInserted` for your case, however implementation is [limpy at best](http://help.dottoro.com/ljmcxjla.php) for IE <10.

Keep in mind, however, that sometimes you can just retain a dynamic reference to the node inserted and operate on that instead:

```
var $newElement = $('<div>Hello World!</div>').appendTo('body');
//...
$newElement.css('color', 'red');
```

[Fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/7wH6R/); effectively you're caching the reference to the element, [which is a good practice to begin with](https://github.com/shichuan/javascript-patterns/blob/master/jquery-patterns/requery.html).

Furthermore, but I do believe DOM inserts are synchronous. I can't find any docos at this stage to back me up, but if you ever try to insert an obscene amount of elements into the document, you'd believe it :)

Comment: I have had the problem with inserting images not being rendered in the browser. I have hacked it with a timeout of a couple of seconds before but that's not really an 100% solution. I will try the reference saving thingie =)

Comment: @MattiasSvensson: that's a tough one without seeing some code; as long as the images have correct vanilla `src` attributes and there isn't any interfering styling, this is a straightforward operation. Check F12 DOM inspector (and network profiler... to make sure your urls are right :) and ask another question perhaps

Comment: >Deprecated: This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events

Comment: Inserting into the document is sync, but the browser will only paint it once the js thread has given back control